# Ubuntu 18.04 netplan bridge. Keep one of physical interfaces down on boot

Tags: bridge, ubuntu-18.04, netplan

I have got an server with Ubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04 recently), which runs two qemu-kvm VMs.

The server has two network interfaces, only the first is connected. The second is not used / wired currently.

For networking I have set up a bridge, which works fine as soon as I manually execute `ip link set enp6s0f1 down`. Before I manually switch it off, I get loads of package loss, as traffic originating from the host seems to use both interfaces.

Networking on the VMs works just fine (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04). All other hosts and the internet is reachable from the VMs. The VMs are reachable from all the hosts in the network.

The netplan configuration:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd

 ethernets:
   enp6s0f0:
     optional: true
   enp6s0f1:
     optional: true

 bridges:
   br0:
     interfaces:
       - enp6s0f0
     addresses: [10.0.0.11/24]
     gateway4: 10.0.0.1
     nameservers:
       search:
         - domain.example.com
       addresses:
         - "10.0.0.25"
         - "10.0.0.26"
```

For completeness after manual `ip link set enp6s0f1 down`:

```
andi@node-002:~$ ifconfig
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::c804:4dff:febe:597e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ca:04:4d:be:59:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1261  bytes 87931 (87.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 126  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 537  bytes 191015 (191.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp6s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::230:48ff:febb:9124  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:30:48:bb:91:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1036  bytes 118241 (118.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 425  bytes 204536 (204.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  memory 0xdc020000-dc040000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 144  bytes 13404 (13.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 144  bytes 13404 (13.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fed5:32c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:d5:32:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1199  bytes 205808 (205.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1839  bytes 278772 (278.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe12:52c9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:12:52:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1030  bytes 230817 (230.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1567  bytes 214331 (214.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What I have tried so far:

- leaving out the enp6s0f1 interface in netplan
- adding both interfaces into the bridge
- switch off the second interface in BIOS, but it's not possible
- create a network hook script to switch off the interface post-up. But I guess I did something wrong here

The post-up script */etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d*:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip link set enp6s0f1 down
```

Edit: I found a workaround. But I do not consider this as a solution to the problem. Currently not needing and wiring the second network interface, configuring with a static IP in an unused subnet will not lead to lost packages. It works, but it's not nice. Hence, I will not post this as answer.

This is the workaround `/etc/netplan/config.yaml`:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd

 ethernets:
   enp6s0f0:
     optional: true
   enp6s0f1:
     addresses: [10.254.0.10/24] # <- static IP in different subnet.
     optional: true

 bridges:
   br0:
     interfaces:
       - enp6s0f0
     addresses: [10.0.0.11/24]
     gateway4: 10.0.0.1
     nameservers:
       search:
         - domain.example.com
       addresses:
         - "10.0.0.25"
         - "10.0.0.26"
```

Looking forward for a better solution.

Comment: What happens when you leave enp6s0f1 out of the ethernets block?

Comment: @Journeymen Geek it's getting configured by network manager.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option: `ignore-carrier` that needs to be set to `true`

```
ignore-carrier (boolean) – since 0.104

(networkd back end only) Allow the specified interface to be configured even if it has no carrier.
```